# How to play audio using libao and FFmpeg in C?

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a simple prototype application that opens a video file and plays its audio. I am using the FFmpeg libraries (libavcodec, libavformat, etc) to open and decode the video, and I am attempting to use libao to play the audio. I tried looking up code examples but a lot of them either don't work or use deprecated functions.

So far, I managed to come up with this:

```c
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <ao/ao.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    AVFormatContext* format_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    int audio_stream_index = -1;
    AVCodecContext* codec_ctx = NULL;
    AVCodec* codec = NULL;
    AVPacket packet;
    AVFrame* frame = NULL;
    ao_device* device = NULL;
    ao_sample_format sample_format;
    uint8_t* output_buffer = NULL;
    int output_linesize;

    avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, "test.mp4", NULL, NULL);
    avformat_find_stream_info(format_ctx, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < format_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (format_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audio_stream_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(NULL);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, format_ctx->streams[audio_stream_index]->codecpar);
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codec_ctx->codec_id);
    avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, NULL);

    // Initialize libao
    ao_initialize();
    int driver_id = ao_default_driver_id();

    sample_format.bits = 16;
    sample_format.channels = 2;
    sample_format.rate = 44100;
    sample_format.byte_format = AO_FMT_NATIVE;
    sample_format.matrix = 0;
    device = ao_open_live(driver_id, &sample_format, NULL);
    if (!device) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open audio device\n");
        return 1;
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();

    while (av_read_frame(format_ctx, &packet) >= 0) {
        if (packet.stream_index == audio_stream_index) {
            int ret = avcodec_send_packet(codec_ctx, &packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error sending packet for decoding\n");
                break;
            }

            while (ret >= 0) {
                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(codec_ctx, frame);
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                    break;
                }
                else if (ret < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error during decoding\n");
                    break;
                }

                ao_play(device, (char*)frame->data[0], frame->nb_samples * 2 * frame->channels);
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }

    // Clean up
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
    ao_close(device);
    ao_shutdown();
    av_freep(&output_buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the closest I have gotten to play audio. It plays audio but there is a lot of static sound in the background. I did try using using `frame->linesize[0]` for `num_bytes` in `ao_play` but that didn't produce a sound that sounded at all like the video.

Is there something I am doing wrong or missing?

EDIT: While doing more testing, I managed to find out that the above code sample outputs pure static in the left speaker, however, in the right speaker, it does play the audio, albeit heavily distorted?